# Complement of a Cayley graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $X(G,S)$ be the (undirected) Cayley graph, with $G$ group and $S \subseteq G$ such that $1_G \notin S$ and $S=S^{-1}$.
Is the complement of $X$ a Cayley graph?

Comment: It seems to me that the ideal answer to this question has been given (but not accepted).  I have voted to close the question as no longer relevant -- I don't think we need to see it popping back up again *ad infinitum*.

Answer (score 3):

The complete graph on $|G|$ vertices is a Cayley graph for $S=G\setminus\{1_G\}$. Its complement, the graph without edges, is not a Cayley graph.

Comment: Isn't it the Cayley graph (under tbg's defintion) for $S=\emptyset$?

Comment: @Robin Chapman: usually, $S$ is assumed to be a generating set. 

Comment: Amongst people who actually work with the things, Cayley graphs are not required to be connected.  For example, there is Sabidussi's
theorem which asserts that a graph is a Cayley graph for the group
$G$ if and only if $G$ acts regularly on its vertices.

Comment: If S is not required to be a generating set, then the answer to the original question is immediately and trivially yes. The partition of G into S and its complement set is mirrored in an obvious way in the partition of the complete graph into X and its complement graph. So requiring S to be a generating set is one possible way of trying to make the question be not so boring, but as my answer shows it still doesn't succeed in doing so.